# How can I get which blocks a file uses that is located inside a virtual file system I created?

Tags: c, linux, filesystems, block

How can I get which blocks a file uses that is located inside a virtual file system I created in Linux?

I'm trying to read the disk in raw mode and find out which blocks are allocated for a given file, inside a C program.

I suppose I need to parse the FAT table but I'm not sure how to proceed. Any ideas?

Any help is appreciated.

This is how I created the virtual file system:

```
sudo su
dd if=/dev/zero of=disk.img bs=1k count=100000
losetup /dev/loop0 disk.img
mkdosfs -s 1 -F 32 /dev/loop0 100000
mkdir /mnt/mydisk
mount -o loop -t vfat /home/a/os/p5/disk.img /mnt/mydisk
cd /mnt/mydisk
-do staff, add files and directories
```

Answer (score 0):

It's looks like some sort of student assignment. Find nice description of [FAT32 here](https://www.pjrc.com/tech/8051/ide/fat32.html).